# Failed to create App Service Managed Certificate

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to create a **free App Service Managed Certificate** for my Azure Web App using the feature that was announced yesterday at ignite ([Secure your Custom Domains at no cost with App Service Managed Certificates](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/secure-your-custom-domains-at-no-cost-with-app-service-managed-certificates-preview/)).

I did add and verified a non-root custom-domain using a CNAME-Record. When I click on the button on the *Create App Service Managed Certificates (Preview)* dialog, I get the following error:

> Failed to create App Service Managed Certificate for hostname
>   xxx.yyy.com Error Details: The gateway did not receive a response
>   from 'Microsoft.Web' within the specified time period.

Here is a screenshot of the error:
[image]

I tried this multiple times now, without success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to create the certificate using an App Service Plan located in **Central US** (West Europe wasn't working). I also mentioned that issue in my [blog post](https://about-azure.com/secure-your-azure-app-service-using-free-ssl-tls-certificates/).

Comment: This issue is still occuring for West Europe. Is it something intermittent?

Comment: @michalczerwinski Hm, should also work in West Europe now, maybe try it again later?

Comment: I'm still getting the same error right now for West Europe.

Comment: i have same issue

Comment: Your blogpost disappeared

Comment: @DdW Sorry for the late response. I fixed the link (I migrated my site from wordpress.com to wordpress.org)...